# Storing client secret on client side

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm using an external service called [auth0](https://auth0.com/) in order to get an access token and let my users use my api. Auth0 is using Oauth2 protocol.

In short The user adds a username and a password, I'm doing a call to auth0 by using a client_id (apps have an id) and client_secret and I get an jwt access token in return. Then from there I carry this access token to have access to my own api since I can check its validity.

I have been looking around about how secure it is to store client_id and client_secret on the client side (e.g. web (javascript)/mobile (native or hybrid with ionic)) and everybody was saying that it's not secure since everybody can reverse engineer the code and get the client_id and client_secret. Ok...I can take it...what Can I do with them if I don't have credentials in order to get the access token?

Given that I don't want to store the client_id and the client_secret, one solutions I have thought is to make a direct call to my api (Java) with the credentials and then my api make a call to auth0 and return the corresponding access token. In this way the client_id and client_secret is stored in the backend and somebody cannot get them easily. Is that safe?

However I have some endpoints, e.g. creating use account, sending sms for phone validation etc, that cannot have credentials. How do I protect the api in such case? If I can't store my own access token on the client side how could I get an access token and access my own api without credentials?

Thanks

Comment: I have seen OAuth2 servers accepting the request without the `client_secret`, or with an empty one. If that's not possible, maybe you can use the token-flow instead of the code-flow.

Comment: Hi @martinstoeckli. Could you give me any links on that?

Comment: I'm successfully using it this way for accessing Google-Drive and One-Drive, have a look at https://github.com/martinstoeckli/SilentNotes/blob/master/src/VanillaCloudStorageClient/OAuth2CloudStorageClient.cs [line 149 and 102]. There is also an info in the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#exchange-authorization-code).

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution that OAuth spec suggests is that you could have three different servers for your application.

client-side
backend server and an additional authentication server.

The preferred way of doing this would be that the client would send the user credentials to the authentication server. The authentication server would be a back-end server which contains the client secret
The authentication server will authenticate the credentials and return back the token.

The client will then use the token obtained from the authentication server to access the resource API server.

If you wanna know more check out this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rCkDE2me_qk

Comment: Hi Sasuke. Thanks for your response. This is what I've had in my mind. This answers how to protect clientid/secret on the client side. However this doesn't answer the other two things I've mentioned. First why it's insecure to store client_secret/id on the client side given that in order to get an access token (jwt) you need username/password that only the user knows. And the other thing is how I protect an API which cannot have username/password e.g. sms validation of phone numbers, sign up, email validation etc

Comment: Hi @SymeonMattes, It's not advisable to store client_secret/id on the client side since any application (extensions) on the client-side could possibly get the client_secret, Its not necessarily easy to get them but its possible and best practice not to store it on client-side. As for you other question to protect the API you can verify the token that you send along with your request in the API server. You would use the same client secret on the API side to verify if the token is valid and the user has been authenticated

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion you are almost certainly using the wrong OAuth flow.  I use Auth0 with Ionic as both a web app and a native Cordova app.  I don't have the client secret in my client code at all.

If you follow the Auth0 quickstarts (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstarts), you should be choosing (Native/Mobile App) if you are deploying to app stores, and (Single-Page App) if you are deploying the web version of Ionic.  From there you can pick Cordova (for native) or Angular (for SPA).  These should give you instructions that implement OAuth flows which DO NOT require your client secret.  My guess would be you are referencing a "Regular Web App" quickstart, which runs server-side and CAN safely hold the client secret.  That's not the world you're coding in if you are using Ionic Hybrid/Native.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know these things. Though I have as specs that the login page should reside on the client. What you/auth0 mention has the following: You have a link on client that redirects you to a login page in auth0 (ok it can be custom), you put the credentials and then with the access token you're redirected back to the application in order to access your own custom API. This contradicts though to what I want to achieve as UX, However, because I know that It's not secure the approach I have now I'm looking for different alternatives.

Comment: I see. In your OP you didn't mention you have a requirement to keep the login form in the app (without linking out). If your server-side API does your authentication for you, having your client_secret there is fine. There are pros/cons here though. You are likely reducing your security on the client-side by doing a non-OAuth compliant implementation (just passing user/pass to your API).  The benefit to using Auth0's client libraries is they (hopefully) handle making your client-side app follow the OAuth specs for native & SPA. So the UX may be preferred in-app, but that may be less secure.

Comment: ok...thank! That's what I've thought. I wanted though to be sure for that.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider wrapping the call to Auth0 into your own server side implementation as safe. Your API takes user credentials and then calls Auth0 and this way your client_id/secret are secure on your server and the client can be reverse-engineered all the way without compromising your security.

Regarding the other APIs which cannot have credentials you are pretty much out of luck. Their very use case is to be used by an unauthenticated third party, so at least the account creation API cannot really be protected. However you can still use some nicely designed constraints to limit the attack surface. E.g. you can require an email address/phone number to register and you will not allow the same address/phone number twice. If you set up your process that you first need to confirm your email address before you can validate your phone number this will make the life of an attacker a lot harder. He would need a real working email address, and some automation to receive your confirmation mails before he could get to call your SMS service. You could also rate-limit the service per IP-address so an attacker cannot cause your SMS cost to skyrocket by issuing a lot of calls for SMS validation in a short period of time.

Comment: Hi Jan. Thanks for your answer...it's very clear! However I still don't get why it's unsafe to store client_id/secret on the client side (ok somebody get's them...I don't care), given that in order to get access to my api he needs to get an access token from auth0. And in order to get access from there he needs client_id/secret (stored in application) and username/password that only he knows.

Comment: Because if I read the API of Auth0 correctly you can use the client_id/secret to obtain an access token for the management API. Using the management API you can get a list of all your users (including email address, etc.). This is a data leak waiting to happen. And you could wreak all kinds of other havoc as well (just check the API https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2/). This is why you should not put this information anywhere where an inquisitive end user could get to it.